# Typescript - Schema phone number make validator accepts values and empty string

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, validation, schema

I have this schema validator on my back-end:

```
private static model: Schema = {

'user.phone': {
            in: 'body',
            isString: true,
            trim: true,
            matches: {
                options: [/^\(?[1-9]{2}\)?(?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}$/]
            },
            customSanitizer: {
                options: (value: string) => {
                    return value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                }
            },
            errorMessage: 'Invalid phone number'
        },
};
```

But I want it to accept empty strings too when is the case. I don't want to remove the regex because when it has the phone number it should do all of above

I've tried using

```
optional: true
```

but didn't work..

Comment: Try `/^(?:\(?[1-9]{2}\)?(?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4})?$/`, this wraps it into optional group

Comment: Try where exactly?

Comment: Instead of the regex you have in `options`